# Unable to connect to openshift using Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, openshift, openshift-online

> Openshift throws an InvalidCredentialsOPenShiftException saying that I'm not authorized to access "https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/user". Does anybody know how to deal with this in Intellij.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: The information shown is for the retired OpenShift Online v2. Do you see an option for OpenShift Online v3?

Comment: There's no OpenShift Online V3; however there's OpenShift Origin V3

Comment: Give that a try

Comment: Just tries it. It automatically points to localhost asking for 'oc.exe' path; but no luck. ERROR: Cannot connect to "com.openshift.restclient.OpenShiftExeption": Could not get resource ~ in namespace: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Comment: Are you running OpenShift on localhost, or running on OpenShift Online?

Comment: I guess it's online. I have created a jboss+MySQL+tomcat app. What I am trying to achieve here is to integrate intellij and OpenShift so that I can edit and test the app in the real-time. This is the first time I have tried hosting and believe me the process is tiring with no proper guidelines for this newer version....And thanks a lot for your responses

Comment: Sure! The docs (https://docs.openshift.com) definitely provide some guidance if you haven't seen them yet. I honestly haven't tested the intellij plug-in and I don't have my computer in front of me...I'll play with it tomorrow and post back what I find out =)

Comment: I appreciate your effort and thank you once again. And yeah, I'll go through that link:)

Answer (score 1):

The GUI has changed and seems to work better in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3 (currently available via [EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/)). Before I got different errors from "com.openshift.restclient", these are now gone.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Two related Bugtickets which fix things related to OpenShift Integration in IDEA 2018.3:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-179768
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-176760